# Different behavior of dataframe.loc[:, new_cols] and dataframe[new_cols] when creating new columns to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to add shifted columns to a dataframe, and found that dataframe.loc[:, new_cols] = dataframe.loc[cols].shift(1) and dataframe[new_cols] = dataframe.loc[cols].shift(1) behave differently with the latter yielding the expected result. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
new_cols = ['col1_lag1', 'col2_lag2']
```

`df.loc[:, new_cols] = df.loc[cols].shift(1)` would give all NANs in the two new columns. `df[new_cols] = df.loc[cols].shift(1)` behaves as expected.
Could anyone help me with explaining this difference please? Thanks!

The result of `df.loc[:, new_cols] = df.loc[cols].shift(1)` is:

| col1 | col2 | col1_lag1 | col2_lag2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 2 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 3 | NaN | NaN |

`df.loc[:, new_cols] = df.loc[cols].shift(1).values` yield the correct result though.